# Transfer user profile to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, transfer

I have a laptop and a new PC, each with windows 8 installed. I have my user account/profile on my laptop and need the same exact thing on my new PC, that is all my documents on my desktop, my chrome bookmarks, saved links etc (basically everything). Is that possible?
If yes, please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have my user account/profile on my laptop and need the same on my new PC

You can use Windows Easy Transfer:

> Microsoft offers their own tool, known as “Windows Easy Transfer.”
>   It’s built into Windows. The tool is built into Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.
>   Launch it by tapping the Windows key to open the Start menu or Start
>   screen, typing “Easy Transfer” without the quotes to search for it,
>   and pressing Enter.
>
> [image]

Source [How to Quickly Transfer Your Files and Settings to a New PC (or Mac)](https://www.howtogeek.com/211256/how-to-quickly-transfer-your-files-and-settings-to-a-new-pc-or-mac/)

The above source link also includes some other ways to transfer your settings.

Comment: Is this transfer 100% efficient and successful or is there any risk of loss of data?

Also, will my Google chrome settings also be reproduced on my new PC with all my bookmarks, saved links etc?

Comment: @Zahra I've no idea. I've never used it.